# How to include "CHECK" constraint to backup done via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, backup, check-constraints

When I export my database from phpMyAdmin (quick method), it does not include `CHECK` constraints. However, when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`, I see the constraints. Moreover, foreign constraints are backed up.

In addition, when I take the backup using mysqldump, `CHECK` constraints are included in the file.

**Is there any way to tell phpMyAdmin to include the `CHECK` constraints in the backup?**

I have checked the "custom" method, but I do not see any option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHECK constraints are not yet supported by the latest phpMyAdmin version 5.2.0.

This is overdue, because CHECK constraints have been supported since MySQL 8.0.16 (2019-04-25) and MariaDB 10.2.1 (2016-07-04).

There are issues showing that they are aware of the feature request.

- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13592
- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16224

They currently schedule it for the phpMyAdmin 5.3.0 milestone, but they have not publicized a due date for that milestone. The intervals between milestones are irregular, between 4 and 13 months. For example, here's the history of recent milestones:

- 4.8.0: 2018-05-24
- 4.9.0: 2019-06-04
- 5.0.0: 2019-12-26
- 5.1.0: 2022-01-21
- 5.2.0: 2022-05-11

So your guess is as good as mine when it will be released.

In the meantime, you must use mysqldump.